brew installed mongo-community@4.4 can't configure for replSet
I have a brew installed mongodb-community@4.4 running on MacOS Sonoma 14.6.1 (23G93). I'm following these instructions to configure it for replica sets, but when I add the replication configuration to mongo.conf, the server won't run.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
security:
  authorization: enabled

The brew restart... says it worked...
$ brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.4
Stopping `mongodb-community@4.4`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community@4.4` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.4)
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community@4.4` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.4)

But I can't connect with a shell, and subsequent brew services list says there is some problem.
The logs don't show anything out of the usual.
What does "error 512" mean when I check brew list services?
$ brew services list
Name                  Status     User   File
mongodb-community@4.4 error  512 rkuhar ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.4.plist
postgresql@14         started    rkuhar ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist
redis                 started    rkuhar ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
unbound               none

What does "error 5" mean when I try brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.4
$ brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.4
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/862776026 /Users/rkuhar/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.4.plist` exited with 5.

How does one configure mongo.conf for "single member replica set" in mongo-community@4.4?

Have a look at the logfile usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log. Why do you install an outdated version of MongoDB?

@WernfriedDomscheit the logs don't have anything spectacular. I install 4.4 because that is what we are using in prod.

Hard to believe, it should state the problem. Can you start it manually, with mongod --config ...
